# Make infoWindow like Google map's default infoWindow that shows info from Google Places

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

We have a Google Local profile (or Google Places) for our business and we have added multiple locations for each store. The requirement is to embed a map in each store page of our website with the accurate location of the store and to display an infoWindow just like it's been displayed from Google's map. Example below:

[image]

I have read the API's documentation but I can't seem to find a clear answer as to the way of referencing a store that already exists in the map. If I add the address of the store, I usually have a 2nd marker that is not on the exact location of the store. Example below:

[image]

If I add longitude and latitude I get 2 markers again (one on top of the other) but then again these markers do not relate to each other as they have different infoWindows. And one major issue is that by using the Places API I can't get the info just like Google does (I get `undefined`). Example:

[image]

Questions:

1. How can I **really** relate (or reference) to the store's location and the Google's Place location and have just one marker with the Google's info in it?
2. How can I reference to a specific store based on Google's Place profile, which has a business with multiple store locations and link it to the "Store" marker that already exists in the map?

Attempts:

1. I tried locating the store based on `PlacesService` and `nearbySearch` with a keyword of the store name. [**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/otinanaipali/qCZZ2/1/). The problem is that I have 2 markers on the map if I zoom in at maximum level.
2. One more issue is that I have 81 stores and it's hard to hard-code the coordinates for each store in each webpage. So, since I have the address in each page I tried `geocoding` to get `longlat`. This wasn't very accurate way because it seems that `geocode` snaps to a nearby area and not exactly on the store. **[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/otinanaipali/84KsB/)**.
3. I tried `PlacesService` with the `reference string` for identifying the store's location based on Google's Place profile. **[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/otinanaipali/7GBSE/2/)**. However, there's not an easy way to retrieve the `reference string` for each store and another issue is that I need hardcoded coordinates to center the map in the area of the store (too much work for 81 stores).

Expected solutions/suggestions:

I would like to fully utilize our Google's Places profile that includes all the stores info. BTW, each store now has a Google+ page created automatically by Google. I would like a suggestion on how to utilize the automatically created Store marker (like in 1st picture) and have the exact same `infoWindow` like Google's default (1st picture) with some sort of a reference ID from our Google's Places profile.

I apologize for this long question but I had to further explain all my attempts.

Comment: why is it hard to hardcode 81 coordinates? Create a single js-file with the coordinates and use it in as much webpages as you want to

Comment: @Dr.Molle As I mentioned in my post, I need to fully utilize Google's Places profile page which includes all stores data with all coordinates. So, I think it wouldn't be very wise to re-enter the coordinates again for each store when (I think) there should be a way of fetching them directly from Google+ page. I just need to know the way of linking (possibly) the G+ page ID or GPlace API key with the the map and display the infowindow of the store that is automatically generated by G Maps. (I hope it makes sense)

Comment: When you want to request the data from the plus-page request ist,  when you want to request the data for the place, request it too(there are API's for both cases). When you want to access the automatic infowindows of the POI's in a map: you can't.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Can you please point me to the API to request data from plus-page? Also, please make your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Comment: @Dr.Molle BTW are you here to help or downvote every question you don't like? Also, do you ever reply with an answer? It's the 2nd question I make about GMaps API and I get a downvote from you and you didn't create or update an answer... No offense but I'm just curious

Comment: Like every user I have the option to up-and downvote a question. Currently I have voted 2,184x up and 1,529x down. In my profile you may see that I have answered 2245 times(1 answer to your other gmap-question), I don't see there any problem.

Comment: @Dr.Molle and the reason of downvoting this question is.....? 1. Question doesn't show research effort? 2. Question is unclear? 3. Question is not useful? Oh! I have the answer: None of the above! I described all of my efforts based on the research I've made. I include 2 very clear questions. I've seen other posts with related questions but no answer. This means that any answer given may be useful for future reference!!! So, I conclude: this is a bad habit of you to downvote without clear criteria even if it's your right to do so.

Comment: Well, you may think your question is useful, I may have another opinion.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: @SteveHolland I ended up using the reference ID that each GPlace provides. Using this id you can retrieve the exact same info and map marker position as Google's default infowindow. However, it's impossible to disable Google's infowindow but I guess I can live with that as long as the info and position is 100% accurate.