# Google Info Windows To show default content

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have an application where a user can enter the location of a place in a text area and then it gets the information from this place from the Google Maps JavaScript API; so it gets the address, latitude, longitude, etc.

I have it load this map on the page and it shows a marker on the lat/long coordinates. when the page is loaded it opens a Info Window. However I don't want to have to create custom content for each place. I want to get the information from googles api and just display it.

Is there anything like this available?

Below is my code for the map/marker/info window

```
var lat = parseFloat(latitude);
    var lng = parseFloat(longitude);

    var map;

    function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location-map'), {
            center: myLatLng,
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 15
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "Use pin to point your exact locality"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but if you've already got the address info from the Google Maps API would you not just use that data as the `content` when you create the marker?

Comment: What information do you want to get from Google's API? Which API/service?

Comment: I see, So you're saying I could get the address, postal code, name of the place,etc and just pass them and display them in the content window. What would that look like? Something like  "content: address" ?

Comment: I would essentially be wanting to do something like this. http://imgur.com/heYXA2N

Comment: That "default" infowindow isn't available directly (unless you use an embedded map), but you can write code to display something similar using data from the Places Library (and other functionality from the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make infoWindow like Google map's default infoWindow that shows info from Google Places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023451/make-infowindow-like-google-maps-default-infowindow-that-shows-info-from-google)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a business/“default” location marker and infoWindow to Google Maps (v3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454782/how-to-add-a-business-default-location-marker-and-infowindow-to-google-maps-v)

Comment: Oh i see, My apologies for duplicating this issue. It seems there is a plethora of information using google places. I had made the incorrect assumption that I was using the  Google Maps JavaScript API. Thank you for your help.